# Linq GroupJoin with multipe tables

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core

I have te follwing Linq query to get the User and add the UserClaimCollection.

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetCollection()
{
    List<User> result = _identityContext.Users
        .GroupJoin(
            _identityContext.UserClaims,
            u => u.Id,
            uc => uc.UserId,
            (u, uc) => new { user = u, claims = uc })
        .ToList()
        .Select(u => new User(
            new Guid(u.user.Id),
            u.user.UserName,
            u.user.FirstName,
            u.user.LastName,
            u.user.Email,
            new UserClaimCollection(
                u.claims.Select(uc => new UserClaim(uc.ClaimType, uc.ClaimValue)).ToList()
            ))
        ).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

How would i add a second GroupJoin to this selection to add a Role collection?

e.g.

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetCollection()
{
    List<User> result = _identityContext.Users
        .GroupJoin(
            _identityContext.UserClaims,
            u => u.Id,
            uc => uc.UserId,
            (u, uc) => new { user = u, claims = uc })
        .GroupJoin(
            _identityContext.UserRoles,
            u => u.Id,
            ur => ur.UserId,
            (u, ur) => new { user = u, roles= ur })                    
        .ToList()
        .Select(u => new User(
            new Guid(u.user.Id),
            u.user.UserName,
            u.user.FirstName,
            u.user.LastName,
            u.user.Email,
            new UserClaimCollection(
                u.claims.Select(uc => new UserClaim(uc.ClaimType, uc.ClaimValue)).ToList()
            )),
            new UserRoleCollection(
                u.roles.Select(ur => new UserRole(ur.RoleType, ur.RoleValue)).ToList()
            ))
        ).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should have `u => u.user.Id` in the second `GroupJoin`. Remember what the output from the first `GroupJoin` is. You should have the output including all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember the output from the first `GroupJoin` is your new anonymous class, so you that is what is passed into the second `GroupJoin`. I recommend naming the lambda parameters to remind you of that.

```
List<User> result = _identityContext.Users
    .GroupJoin(
        _identityContext.UserClaims,
        u => u.Id,
        c => c.UserId,
        (user, claims) => new { user, claims })
    .GroupJoin(
        _identityContext.UserRoles,
        uc => uc.user.Id,
        roles => roles.UserId,
        (uc, roles) => new { uc.user, uc.claims, roles })                    
    .ToList()
    .Select(ucr => new User(
        new Guid(ucr.user.Id),
        ucr.user.UserName,
        ucr.user.FirstName,
        ucr.user.LastName,
        ucr.user.Email,
        new UserClaimCollection(
            ucr.claims.Select(c => new UserClaim(c.ClaimType, c.ClaimValue)).ToList()
        )),
        new UserRoleCollection(
            ucr.roles.Select(r => new UserRole(r.RoleType, r.RoleValue)).ToList()
        ))
    ).ToList();
```